# Como melhorar a perfomace de um programa dividindo as execuções em processos em liguagem C?

Tags: c, processo, sistema-operacional

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i,j;
    uchar *image;
    camera c;
    point eye;
    point lookat;
    int samples; 
    int s;    
    float rcp_samples;// = 1.0 / (float)samples;
    //char fname[20];
    //ray * rays;
    //color cor;

    //srand ( time(NULL) );

    //---init virtual camera---
    //point eye = {10.0f,400.0f,1000.0f};
    //point eye = {0.0f,2.0f,-20.0f};
    eye.x = 0.0f;
    eye.y = 2.0f;
    eye.z = -20.0f;

    //point lookat = {0.5f,0.0f,0.0f};
    lookat.x = 0.5f;
    lookat.y = 0.0f;
    lookat.z = 0.0f;

    initCamera(&c,eye,lookat,WID,HEI);
    setupCamera(&c);

    //---malloc the image frame---
    image = (uchar *) malloc(c.view.width * c.view.height * 3 * sizeof(uchar));
    if(image == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error. Cannot malloc image frame.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //---just init the image frame with some data---
    initImage(&c,image);

    //---insert random N_SPHERES into the 'data' array
    //generateRandomSpheres();
    generateScene();

    //---insert random N_LIGHTS into the 'lights' array
    generateRandomLightSources();

    //---create a 1D array with primary rays coordinates
    //rays = generatePrimaryRays(&c);

    for(i=0; i<NRAN; i++) urand[i].x = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX - 0.5;
    for(i=0; i<NRAN; i++) urand[i].y = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX - 0.5;
    for(i=0; i<NRAN; i++) irand[i] = (int)(NRAN * ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX));

    //---ray tracing loop---

    samples = 8;
    s = 0;    
    rcp_samples = 1.0 / (float)samples;

    for(i = 0 ; i < c.view.width ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < c.view.height ; j++)
        {
            float r, g, b;
            r = g = b = 0.0;

            for(s=0; s<samples; s++) {
                ray rr = get_primary_ray(&c,i,j,s);    
                color col = trace(c,&rr,0);
                r += col.r;
                g += col.g;
                b += col.b;
            }

            r = r * rcp_samples;
            g = g * rcp_samples;
            b = b * rcp_samples;

            //ray rr = get_primary_ray(&c, i, j, samples); 
            //color clr = trace(c,&rr,0);

            //red green blue color components
            image[ 3* (i * c.view.height + j) + 0] = floatToIntColor(r);
            image[ 3* (i * c.view.height + j) + 1] = floatToIntColor(g);
            image[ 3* (i * c.view.height + j) + 2] = floatToIntColor(b);
        }
    }

    //printPrimaryRays(rays,c.view.width*c.view.height); //for testing only

    if(save_bmp("output_rt.bmp",&c,image) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot write image 'output.bmp'.\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Quero dividir a construção de cada vetor (image) entre processos e depois de processado enviar via PIPE a um processo.

Answer (score 0):

Dificilmente é possível dividir uma tarefa em vários processos, pois precisa que os dados sejam muito independentes (somente para flags e alguns ponteiros para evitar problemas de concorrências), e que os processos fiquem executando por bastante tempo (geralmente até o usuário cancelar), para ser considerado algo viável. Para melhorar o processo de Pipeline, que já é automático do processador, uma dica boa é usar um compilador atualizado, como o do Visual Studio que é muito otimizado para pipeline.

Para sínteses de imagem em tempo real não é possível dividir o processo em dois, pois possui muito dado compartilhado. Para otimizar isso você pode procurar como utilizar as interrupções (rotinas) da Placa gráfica (Integrada ou Dedicada), para realizar cálculos pesados, ou utilizar uma biblioteca gráfica como o OpenGl ou DirectX.

No jogo que eu desenvolvo por exemplo, eu uso uma thread separada para:

- Interface (não embutida na tela gráfica, somente para configurações).
- Carregamento de Arquivos (Imagens e Objetos): Que é destroida quando todos os arquivos são carregados e alterando o valor de um flag global, indicando para a parte gráfica que já pode rodar o que foi carregado.
- Simulação de Física e Processamento Gráfico (utilizando OpenGL).